# Properties about Projection

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $G$ be an operator on Hilbert space $H$ such that kerG is different from {0}.

Let also $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto kerG.

My question is : are there some conditions to impose on $G$ that guarantee the invariance of 
kerP and ImP by $G$

Comment: You mean conditions on $G$ like $G^2=G$ or $G^*G=GG^*$ such that for $H=N\oplus R$ it holds $GN\subseteq N$ and $GR\subseteq R$?

Comment: yes, that I mean what's coditions on $G$?

Comment: But you do not necessarily obtain a linear projection this way, do you?

Answer (score 0):

To have the range of $P$ invariant under $G$ means $PGP=GP$. To have the kernel invariant means $(I-P)G(I-P)=G(I-P)$ or $G-PG-GP+PGP=G-GP$ or $PG=PGP$. So it is necessary that $PG=GP$. But this is also sufficient.